# Why would calling MessageBox[etc]() without a return variable cause the program to crash?

Tags: c++, winapi, messagebox, access-violation, crash

So if I write the following code:

```
MessageBoxA(0, "Yo, wazzup!", "A Greeting From Earth", 0);
```

the program crashes with an access violation when it exits. When I write the code like this:

```
int a;
a = MessageBoxA(0, "Yo, wazzup!", "A Greeting From Earth", 0);
```

it doesn't crash. Now I know why it crashes *when* it crashes thanks to another question I asked, also regarding argument-mismatching, but I don't know *why* it crashes.

**So why does this cause an APPCRASH?** I was always under the impression that calling a function that had a return-type, without actually giving one was safe, example:

```
int SomeFunction (void) {
   std::cout << "Hello ya'll!\n";
   return 42;
}

int main (void) {
   int a;

   // "Correct" ?
   a = SomeFunction();
   a = MessageBoxA(0, "Yo, wazzup!", "A Greeting From Earth", 0);

   // "Incorrect" ?
   SomeFunction();
   MessageBoxA(0, "Yo, wazzup!", "A Greeting From Earth", 0);

}
```

When I run this kind of test "clean" (in a new file) I don't get any errors. **It only seems to give an error with MessageBox/MessageBoxA when run in my program**. Knowing the possible causes would help me pinpoint the error as the project code is too big to post (and I would need my friend's permission to post his code anyway).

**Additional Info:**
Compiler = GCC
Platform = Windows

## EDIT:

**Update**
Thanks everyone for your feedback so far. So I decided to run it through a debugger... Now Code::Blocks doesn't debug a project unless it is loaded from a project file (*.cbp) - AFAIK. So I created an actual project and copy-pasted our project's main file into the projects. Then I ran in debug mode and didn't get so much as a warning. I then compiled in build mode and it ran fine.
Next, I decided to open a new file in Dev-C++ and run it through the debugging and later the final build process and again I got no errors for either build or debug. I cannot reproduce this error in Dev-C++, even with our main file (as in the one that causes the error in Code::Blocks).

**Conclusion**
The fault must lie in Code::Blocks. AFAIK, they both use GCC so I am pretty confused. The only thing I can think of is a version difference or perhaps my compiler settings or something equally obscure. Could optimizer settings or any other compiler settings somehow cause this kind of error?

Comment: Just that should not crash, you have another problem. Please run your program in a debugger, it will help you pinpoint the crash.

Comment: Unless you can give a concrete repro, it never happened

Comment: Its probably stack corruption... How repeatable is it?

Comment: Try running your application under the Application Verifier it often traps corruption errors earlier

Comment: It's possible that the program has a buffer overrun, or is using stale or uninitialised objects, and the extra variable makes the crash go away because you're overwriting that variable instead of something essential.

Comment: Please provide us with a stack trace.

Answer (score 3):

The version with the return value does not crash because it had one int more on the stack. Your erroneous code reads over the bounds of the stack and then runs into an access violation. But if you have more on the stack you will not hit the guard page, because that is just enough extra stack. If the the erroneous code only reads it is sort of OK, but still broken.

We had one bit of WTF inducing code that was like so:

```
char dummy[52];
some_function();
```

There was thankfully a longish comment explaining that removing dummy, makes `some_function` crash. It was in a very old application so nobody dared touch it and the `some_function` was totally different module we had no control over. Oh yea and that application was running smoothly in the field for over 20 years in industrial installations, like refineries or nuclear power plants... ^_^

Comment: @chx101 click on "[rioki](http://stackoverflow.com/users/178306/rioki)" -> Website [riok.org](http://www.rioki.org/) -> [About](http://www.rioki.org/about.html) and you would know beyond a shadow of a doubt.